# How to model datatypes in Python (namedtuple almost there?)

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm coming from a functional programming background, and I want to model
'datatype'-style data as it appears in Rust / ML / Haskell / Typed Racket / etc.

So, for instance:

```
## A binarytree is either
## - Leaf(val), representing a leaf, or
## - Node(left,right), representing a node.
```

It turns out that I'm not alone, and in fact [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604666/functional-style-datatypes-in-python) is essentially asking the same question as I am.

However, the new piece here is that that question's answers make no mention of `namedtuple` (perhaps they predate it?), and in fact namedtuple gets me about 95% of the way there. In fact, there's only one nasty hack, revolving around class names.

Specifically, I can write:

```
from collections import namedtuple;

Leaf = namedtuple('Leaf',['val'])
Node = namedtuple('Node',['left','right'])
```

... and this allows me to construct values in a straightforward way, e.g.:

```
my_tree = Node(Leaf(13),Node(Leaf('zoo'),Leaf(0.003)))
```

However, if I want to figure out whether a given tree is a node or a leaf, things get nasty:

```
if (type(my_tree).__name__ == 'Node'):
    # do something with the node's elements
else:
    # do something with the leaf's elements
```

Specifically, I think the use of the `type` function and the `__name__` property are pretty gross.

Is there a nicer way to do this, or should I just get over it and learn to love the `__name__` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(my_tree ,Node):
```

But type will also work without using `__name__`:

```
if type(my_tree) is Node:
```

Both will return True:

```
In [55]: type(my_tree)  is Node
Out[55]: True

In [56]: isinstance(my_tree, Node)
Out[56]: True
```

the difference being `isinstance` would *Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.*

Comment: Should probably use `type(my_tree) is Node` rather than `==`.